# Execute/trigger CommandButton_Click() automatically when cell is changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA code (in Sheet1) when any cell in Column(I) is changed then a MessageBox is triggered and said: "A value in Column (I) was changed."
I have a CommandButton_Click() (in Sheet2).

What I would like to do is whenever a cell is changed in Column(I) (in Sheet1) make the CommandButton_Click() (in Sheet2) automatically triggered and "clicked" (I mean I'd like to make the button to be executed automatically so I don't have to click manually on the button).
Anytime when the specific column's cells are changed by user or else "call CommandButton_Click()" or make it "True".

Is there a way to make it happen? Thanks for the help!
Best regards: Tom

Comment: then show your code

Comment: just call the button's assigned macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may code like this in Sheet1 code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("I:I"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "A value in Column (I) was changed"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").CommandButton1.Value = True
    End If
End Sub
```